# PL/SQL get the real number of weeks in a year in next 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get the real number of week of the year in next 6 months?

Example: 
13.09.2022 is the 38th week of the year
17.09.2022 is the 38th week of the year
19.09.2022 is the 39th week of the year
.
.
01.01.2023 is the 1th week of the year (Sunday)
02.01.2023 is the 2th week of the year (Monday)
09.01.2023 is the 3th week of the year
.
Next 6 Months

I already know the real number of the week in a year but not in next 6 months, just to the end of the year in the below code.

```
SELECT LISTAGG (
                         DISTINCT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH'),
                         ', ')                              AS MONTHS,
                     TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09')    week_num
                FROM (SELECT mydate,
                               (  (  TRUNC (mydate, 'day')
                                   - TRUNC (TRUNC (mydate, 'yyyy'), 'day'))
                                / 7)
                             + CASE
                                   WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'YYYY'), 'day') =
                                        'sun'
                                   THEN
                                       1
                                   ELSE
                                       0
                               END    AS nr_of_sundays
                        FROM (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'yy') - 1 + LEVEL    AS mydate
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                           TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 12),
                                                  'yy')
                                         - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'yy')))
               WHERE TO_DATE (mydate, 'DD/MM/YY') >=
                     TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY')
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09')
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09');
```

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk8Ik.png)

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original query modified to only show 6 months of data for the next 6 months, starting at the first day of the current month:

```
SELECT LISTAGG (
                         DISTINCT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH'),
                         ', ')                              AS MONTHS,
                     TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09')    week_num
                FROM (SELECT mydate,
                               (  (  TRUNC (mydate, 'day')
                                   - TRUNC (TRUNC (mydate, 'yyyy'), 'day'))
                                / 7)
                             + CASE
                                   WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'YYYY'), 'day') =
                                        'sun'
                                   THEN
                                       1
                                   ELSE
                                       0
                               END    AS nr_of_sundays
                        FROM (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL    AS mydate --
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                           TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 6), --
                                                  'mm') --
                                         - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm'))) --
               WHERE TO_DATE (mydate, 'DD/MM/YY') >=
                     TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY')
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09')
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm09');
            
            SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL    AS mydate 
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                           TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 6), 
                                                  'mm') 
                                         - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm');

MONTHS      WEEK_NUM

JANUARY     01
JANUARY     02
JANUARY     03
JANUARY     04
FEBRUARY , JANUARY      05
FEBRUARY    06
FEBRUARY    07
FEBRUARY    08
FEBRUARY    09
SEPTEMBER   38
SEPTEMBER   39
OCTOBER  , SEPTEMBER    40
...
```

However, because the results only have columns "months" and "week_num" and the order by is by week_num - it will look odd. The first row will be the first week_num of next year. You could add the year to each row. Here is a rewritten query using exactly the same logic but including the year for each row:

```
WITH date_range (mydate) AS
(
   SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm') - 1 + LEVEL
     FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 6),'mm') - TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'mm')
), weeknum_per_date (mydate, nr_of_sundays) AS
(
   SELECT mydate,
          (TRUNC (mydate, 'day') - TRUNC (TRUNC (mydate, 'yyyy'), 'day')) / 7
          + CASE WHEN TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'YYYY'), 'day') = 'sun' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    AS nr_of_sundays 
     FROM date_range
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(mydate, 'YYYY') as year, LISTAGG (DISTINCT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (mydate, 'MONTH'), 'MONTH'),
                         ', ')                              AS MONTHS,
                     TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm00')    week_num
  FROM weeknum_per_date                                            
               WHERE TO_DATE (mydate, 'DD/MM/YY') >=
                     TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY')
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm00'), TO_CHAR(mydate, 'YYYY')
            ORDER BY TO_CHAR(mydate, 'YYYY'), TO_CHAR (nr_of_sundays + 1, 'fm00'); 

year    month      week_num
2022    SEPTEMBER   38
2022    SEPTEMBER   39
2022    OCTOBER  , SEPTEMBER    40
2022    OCTOBER     41
2022    OCTOBER     42
2022    OCTOBER     43
2022    OCTOBER     44
2022    NOVEMBER , OCTOBER      45
2022    NOVEMBER    46
2022    NOVEMBER    47
2022    NOVEMBER    48
2022    DECEMBER , NOVEMBER     49
2022    DECEMBER    50
2022    DECEMBER    51
2022    DECEMBER    52
2022    DECEMBER    53
2023    JANUARY     01
2023    JANUARY     02
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ISO week (which starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday and belongs to whichever year contains the majority of its days) then:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM week_start)
            = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM week_end)
       THEN TO_CHAR(week_start, 'fmMONTH')
       ELSE TO_CHAR(week_start, 'fmMONTH')
            || ', ' || TO_CHAR(week_end, 'fmMONTH')
       END as month,
       TO_CHAR(week_start, 'IW') AS iso_week,
       TO_CHAR(week_start, 'IYYY') AS iso_year
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'IW') + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 AS week_start,
         TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'IW') + LEVEL * 7 - 1 AS week_end
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'IW') + (LEVEL - 1) * 7 <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
);
```

Which outputs:

| MONTH | ISO_WEEK | ISO_YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SEPTEMBER | 37 | 2021 |
| SEPTEMBER | 38 | 2021 |
| SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER | 39 | 2021 |
| OCTOBER | 40 | 2021 |
| OCTOBER | 41 | 2021 |
| OCTOBER | 42 | 2021 |
| OCTOBER | 43 | 2021 |
| NOVEMBER | 44 | 2021 |
| NOVEMBER | 45 | 2021 |
| NOVEMBER | 46 | 2021 |
| NOVEMBER | 47 | 2021 |
| NOVEMBER, DECEMBER | 48 | 2021 |
| DECEMBER | 49 | 2021 |
| DECEMBER | 50 | 2021 |
| DECEMBER | 51 | 2021 |
| DECEMBER, JANUARY | 52 | 2021 |
| JANUARY | 01 | 2022 |
| JANUARY | 02 | 2022 |
| JANUARY | 03 | 2022 |
| JANUARY | 04 | 2022 |
| JANUARY, FEBRUARY | 05 | 2022 |
| FEBRUARY | 06 | 2022 |
| FEBRUARY | 07 | 2022 |
| FEBRUARY | 08 | 2022 |
| FEBRUARY, MARCH | 09 | 2022 |
| MARCH | 10 | 2022 |
| MARCH | 11 | 2022 |
| MARCH | 12 | 2022 |
| MARCH, APRIL | 13 | 2022 |
| APRIL | 14 | 2022 |
| APRIL | 15 | 2022 |
| APRIL | 16 | 2022 |
| APRIL, MAY | 17 | 2022 |
| MAY | 18 | 2022 |
| MAY | 19 | 2022 |
| MAY | 20 | 2022 |
| MAY | 21 | 2022 |
| MAY, JUNE | 22 | 2022 |
| JUNE | 23 | 2022 |
| JUNE | 24 | 2022 |
| JUNE | 25 | 2022 |
| JUNE, JULY | 26 | 2022 |
| JULY | 27 | 2022 |
| JULY | 28 | 2022 |
| JULY | 29 | 2022 |
| JULY | 30 | 2022 |
| AUGUST | 31 | 2022 |
| AUGUST | 32 | 2022 |
| AUGUST | 33 | 2022 |
| AUGUST | 34 | 2022 |
| AUGUST, SEPTEMBER | 35 | 2022 |
| SEPTEMBER | 36 | 2022 |
| SEPTEMBER | 37 | 2022 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4i_b8r3m)